# Android service crashing on boot

Tags: java, android

I have an android foreground service that is supposed to start running when the device boots up. At the boot the banner rolls by signaling that the service has started, however the banner does not stay in the notification bar after the initial notification runs buy. Additionally the service does not continue to run.Below is my manifest, broadcast receiver, and service.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.copyright.Going_Plaid"
android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"
>
    <uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"

    />
<application

    android:allowBackup="true" android:label="Going_Plaid"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <receiver android:name="com.example.copyright.Going_Plaid.autostart">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


    <activity
        android:name="com.example.copyright.Going_Plaid.MainActivity"
        android:label="Going_Plaid">
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    <service
        android:name="com.example.copyright.Going_Plaid.Scan"
        android:exported="false"
        android:enabled="true"
        />





</application>
```

autostart.java:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;


public class autostart extends BroadcastReceiver {
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1){
    Intent intent = new Intent(arg0, Scan.class);
    arg0.startService(intent);
    Log.v("autostart", "service should be started");

    }
}
```

Scan.java:

```
public IBinder onBind(Intent mServiceIntent){return null;}
@Override
public void onCreate(){
startInForeground();
notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

@Override
public int onStartCommand( Intent mServiceIntent,int flags, int startId) {
executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
```

Most of the code has been redacted because I did not think it was relevant. The service does run fine when started through the UI but runs into issues when starting from boot without the user manually starting it. If you need any other information I would be happy to add it. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Can you give the logcat messages of the crash?

Comment: Why is `android:exported="false"`and not set to `true`?

Comment: I had it set to false to restrict what could start the service do you think it would help to set it to true?

Comment: I'm not sure how I would get the logcat since the issue arises right after a restart. I don't think I could start the logcat before the crash has already happened. I don't have that much experience with logcat though so I could be completely off base in that regard.Do you have any suggestions?